# Why does the size of my window.history not decrease?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

When I access the JavaScript variable `window.history.length` I am returned the size of my window history.  As I navigate forward from one page to another and then on to another, the length of `window.history` increases.  As I go back through my history using the browser back button, the value of `window.history` does not decrease even though I am moving back through the history.  Why is this?

Comment: It can decrease if you navigate back a few pages and then visit a different page than you've gone before. Click around a few times on StackOverflow, then check the length. Go back a few pages and check the length again, it should be the same. Click a different length and it will be smaller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of `window.history` as a logically growing list or array of pages visited.  Initially, there is only the initial page.  When you navigate forward, a new entry is added to the end of the list and `window.history.length` increases by one.  When you go back a page, the list does **not** have the entry you were previously at removed.  Instead, it remains and you then have the opportunity to go forward (back to the page you just came back from).

What this means is that you shouldn't use the length of `window.history` as an indicator of how far you are from the start of your browsing session.  For example, if your `window.history.length` has a value of 5 that does **not** mean that if you go back 3 pages you will be at the 2nd page you visited.  `window.history.length` represents the length of the number of pages you have visited in a forward direction but says nothing about where you currently *are* within that list.

If after navigating backwards, you visit a forward page that is not the same as the previous one in the forward chain, the list will be changed and so will the length as you are now no longer able to forward visit the entries that you had previously returned from.

Comment: Then how would you go about checking if you are in the first page of the stack?